# Emacs: Navigation in non-truncate mode

Tags: emacs, navigation

I'm editing a file with very long lines in Emacs.  I've turned on line truncating, and I want to quickly see the last words in each line quickly.

So I move to the end of the first line,  then when I press C-n  it takes me to the next line and the horizontal position is not lost.  But when I do C-v,  it takes me to the beginning of first line in the next page i.e., the horizontal position is getting lost.

Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement `C-v` in terms of `C-n`, something like this:

```
(defun scroll-up-keep-position ()
  (interactive)
  (next-line (window-height)))
(global-set-key [(control v)] 'scroll-up-keep-position)
```

Comment: Great, Thanks! <filler for 15 chr limit>